# How can I build jcal for Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, compilation

I need Windows executables of this project:
https://github.com/ashkang/jcal

I tried adding all .h and a .c files with a `main` to a single Console  non-qt C++ project in Qt Creator but it issues a lot errors like: `\jdate\jdate.c:-1 error: undefined reference to jlocaltime_r'`.

I have also added unknown files like `jasctime_r.3` to the project.

How can I compile this project in Windows?

Comment: What C and H files - project source is JavaScript

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry I linked a project with the same name by mistake. now corrected

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it does indeed work, if you use the GNU build system it is intended for, but you *do* need some code changes to get around missing functions on windows.

- `localtime_r()` and `gmtime_r()` can be replaced with `localtime_s()` and `gmtime_s()` and the arguments swapped.
- for `strptime()`, you need to provide an implementation, here's an [open source one](https://opensource.apple.com/source/lukemftp/lukemftp-3/lukemftp/libukem/strptime.c) that works if you fix the `#includes` and add a `#define TM_YEAR_BASE 1900`.

Put the fixed `strptime.c` in the `sources/libjalali` directory and apply the following patch:

```
diff --git a/sources/configure.ac b/sources/configure.ac
index e623ec9..409d9e7 100644
--- a/sources/configure.ac
+++ b/sources/configure.ac
@@ -66,4 +66,9 @@ if test $installpyjalali = "yes"; then
 fi
 AM_CONDITIONAL([WANT_PYJALALI], [test $installpyjalali = "yes"])

+case $host in
+   *mingw*) targetismingw=yes ;;
+esac
+AM_CONDITIONAL([MINGW], [test x$targetismingw = xyes])
+
 AC_OUTPUT
diff --git a/sources/libjalali/Makefile.am b/sources/libjalali/Makefile.am
index 078c68a..64ef85d 100644
--- a/sources/libjalali/Makefile.am
+++ b/sources/libjalali/Makefile.am
@@ -5,6 +5,9 @@
 lib_LTLIBRARIES = libjalali.la

 libjalali_la_SOURCES = jalali.c jtime.c
+if MINGW
+libjalali_la_SOURCES += strptime.c
+endif

 # 0:0:0
 # 0 -> interface version, changes whenever you change the API
diff --git a/sources/libjalali/jalali.c b/sources/libjalali/jalali.c
index 49fc43f..6e3bdd9 100644
--- a/sources/libjalali/jalali.c
+++ b/sources/libjalali/jalali.c
@@ -28,6 +28,10 @@
 #include "jalali.h"
 #include "jconfig.h"

+#ifdef _WIN32
+#define localtime_r(timep, result) localtime_s((result), (timep))
+#endif
+
 /*
  * Assuming *factor* numbers of *lo* make one *hi*, cluster *lo*s and change
  * *hi* appropriately. In the end:
@@ -49,7 +53,9 @@ const int jalali_month_len[] = { 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30,
 const int accumulated_jalali_month_len[] = { 0, 31, 62, 93, 124, 155, 186,
                                              216, 246, 276, 306, 336 };

+#ifndef _WIN32
 extern char* tzname[2];
+#endif

 /*
  * Jalali leap year indication function. The algorithm used here
diff --git a/sources/libjalali/jtime.c b/sources/libjalali/jtime.c
index 319dbdd..ba8ec1a 100644
--- a/sources/libjalali/jtime.c
+++ b/sources/libjalali/jtime.c
@@ -27,6 +27,11 @@
 #include "jalali.h"
 #include "jtime.h"

+#ifdef _WIN32
+#define localtime_r(timep, result) localtime_s((result), (timep))
+#define gmtime_r(timep, result) gmtime_s((result), (timep))
+#endif
+
 const char* GMT_ZONE = "UTC";
 const char* GMT_ZONE_fa = "گرینویچ";
 const char* jalali_months[] = { "Farvardin", "Ordibehesht", "Khordaad",
@@ -65,7 +70,9 @@ const char* tzname_fa[2] = { "زمان زمستانی", "زمان تابستان
 static char in_buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE] = {0};
 static struct jtm in_jtm;

+#ifndef _WIN32
 extern char* tzname[2];
+#endif
 extern const int jalali_month_len[];

 void in_jasctime(const struct jtm* jtm, char* buf)
diff --git a/sources/libjalali/jtime.h b/sources/libjalali/jtime.h
index fd658f1..48b4d9a 100644
--- a/sources/libjalali/jtime.h
+++ b/sources/libjalali/jtime.h
@@ -56,6 +56,10 @@ extern struct jtm* jlocaltime_r(const time_t* timep, struct jtm* result);

 extern int jalali_to_farsi(char* buf, size_t n, int padding, char* pad, int d);

+#ifdef _WIN32
+extern char *strptime(const char *buf, const char *fmt, struct tm *tm);
+#endif
+
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
diff --git a/sources/src/jdate.c b/sources/src/jdate.c
index 8a47e19..cae0329 100644
--- a/sources/src/jdate.c
+++ b/sources/src/jdate.c
@@ -34,6 +34,11 @@
 #include "../libjalali/jtime.h"
 #include "jdate.h"

+#ifdef _WIN32
+#define localtime_r(timep, result) localtime_s((result), (timep))
+#define gmtime_r(timep, result) gmtime_s((result), (timep))
+#endif
+
 extern char* optarg;

 /*
```

Then, get [`msys2`](http://www.msys2.org/), start its shell and install packages:

```
pacman -S mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc msys/autoconf msys/automake msys/libtool
```

This should be enough I guess.

Now you can use the following commands in the `sources` directory to build it:

```
autoreconf -i
./configure
make
```

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by "apply the following patch"?

Comment: use the `patch` command, it should work in "msys" as well. save the patch to a file (extension `.diff` is common) and inside the jcal root directory, do `patch -p1 </path/to/file.diff`